# How to search with the value of a cookie in php - codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, search, cookies

I have a popup dialog on first visit. you can set the postcode with a radius. onsubmit the cookies are set and shown on the main webpage:

You can try this here: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl

Now you see a searchform for searching factories in my database. my factories table looks like this:

```
Factories
- - - - - 
idfactories
factoryname
postcode
place
telephonenumber
email
website
profile
adress
```

note i have a postcode field in my table. so how do i search in that table using the postcode i set using cookies?

my code for setting the cookie:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="postcode">
    <select name="radius">
        <option disabled selected>Afstand</option>
        <option>5km</option>
        <option>10km</option>
        <option>15km</option>
        <option>25km</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Opslaan">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="afstand" value="true" />
    </form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['postcode']))
    {
        setcookie('postcode', $_POST['postcode'], time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        setcookie('radius', $_POST['radius'], time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        header("location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
    };

?>

<?php

if (isset($_POST["set_radius"])) {
}
?>
```

My searchquery in my model:

```
function get_search($match)
{
    $this->db->like('Bedrijfsnaam', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Postcode', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Plaats', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Telefoonnummer', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Email', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Website', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Profiel', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Adres', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Categorie', $match);

    $this->db->join('bedrijven', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven = bedrijven.idbedrijven');
    $this->db->join('categorieen', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen = categorieen.idcategorieen');
    $this->db->group_by('bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen');

    $query = $this->db->get('bedrijfcategorieen');

    return $query->result();
}
```

my controller function:

```
function searchresults()
{   
    $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> base_url().'home/search' ,'title' => 'Bedrijven Zoeken' );            
    $this->breadcrumbs->method = array('link'=> base_url().'home/searchresults' ,'title' => 'Zoekresultaten' );
    $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match);
    $this->load->view('views/header');
    $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
    $this->load->view('views/footer');
    $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijven_tags();
}
```

i tried using `$this->input->cookie('search');` but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I don't see where you save your cookie with key "swarch".  I see postcode and radius only. Then you have to retrieve the cookie like

```
$this->input->cookie('postcode')
```

Anyway if you are setting the correct cookie. Are you loading the cookie helper?

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
```

Cheers!

Comment: i made a typo it has to be 'search' but i am using the cookie helper. i just need that codeigniter knows that the cookie postcode means the field 'Postcode' in my factories table. and that i can search using the value of that cookie so it searches for it in the postcode row.

Comment: i never thought it was this simple. i fixed it by doing $match = $this->input->cookie('postcode'); Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by simply adding the following code to my controller function

```
$match = $this->input->cookie('postcode');
```

Codeigniter is awesome!