# Prevent overriding queries in controller function - codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, search, cookies

I have a searchfunction for searching factories using your postcode.

this is based on a question i asked earlier today: [How to search with the value of a cookie in php - codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010012/how-to-search-with-the-value-of-a-cookie-in-php-codeigniter)
I have a query like this:

> $match = $this->input->post('search');

this is working fine but when i add:

```
$match = $this->input->cookie('postcode');
```

it's overriding the first $match. how can i use both searchqueries without overriding eachother?

How do i set two variables like $match1 and $match2? when i do that it searches on factories only and not on postcode. i just want to have results of postcode and search factories who have a postcode like 9101 for example

My model function:

```
    function get_search($match, $match2)
    {
        $this->db->like('Bedrijfsnaam', $match);
        $this->db->or_like('Postcode', $match);
        $this->db->or_like('Plaats', $match);
        $this->db->or_like('Telefoonnummer', $match);
        $this->db->or_like('Email', $match);
        $this->db->or_like('Website', $match);
        $this->db->or_like('Profiel', $match);
        $this->db->or_like('Adres', $match);
        $this->db->or_like('Categorie', $match);

        $this->db->join('bedrijven', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven = bedrijven.idbedrijven');
        $this->db->join('categorieen', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen = categorieen.idcategorieen');
        $this->db->group_by('bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen');

        $query = $this->db->get('bedrijfcategorieen');

        return $query->result();
    }
```

My controller function:

```
    function searchresults()
    {   
        $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> base_url().'home/search' ,'title' => 'Bedrijven Zoeken' );            
        $this->breadcrumbs->method = array('link'=> base_url().'home/searchresults' ,'title' => 'Zoekresultaten' );
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
        $match = $this->input->post('search');
        $match2 = $this->input->cookie('postcode');
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2);
        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijven_tags();
    }
```

Hope someone knows what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem like this:

i deleted my old model and instead i made it like this:

```
function get_search($match, $match2)
{
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM (`bedrijfcategorieen`) 
        JOIN `bedrijven` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven` = `bedrijven`.`idbedrijven` 
        JOIN `categorieen` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idcategorieen` = `categorieen`.`idcategorieen` 
        WHERE (`Bedrijfsnaam` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Plaats` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Telefoonnummer` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Email` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Website` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Profiel` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Adres` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Categorie` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%') 
        AND (Postcode LIKE '%".$this->input->post('cookie')."%')

        GROUP BY `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven`";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        return $result->result();

  }
```

this way it searches for two things. the postcode who is located in the factories table and the postcode cookie who is set.

My controller:

```
    function search()
    {
        $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> base_url().'home/search' ,'title' => 'Bedrijven Zoeken' );
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('views/search', $data);
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
    }

    function searchresults()
    {   
        $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> base_url().'home/search' ,'title' => 'Bedrijven Zoeken' );            
        $this->breadcrumbs->method = array('link'=> base_url().'home/searchresults' ,'title' => 'Zoekresultaten' );
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
        $match = $this->input->post('search');
        if(strlen($this->input->post('cookie')) > 0){ $match2 = $this->input->post('cookie'); } else{ $match2 = '9101'; }
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2);
        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijven_tags();
    }
```

My views:

**Search:**

```
<div style="clear: both; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
<div class="path"><?php echo $breadcrumbs ?></div>  
<div id="bigcontent">
<h1>Bedrijven zoeken</h1>
<hr>
<br/>
<br />
<p>Voer een zoekterm en postcode in om bedrijven te zoeken.</p>
<br/>
<form name="input" action="searchresults" method="post">
<input type="search" onchange="validate()" placeholder="Zoeken..." name="search" size="70">
<input type="search" onchange="validate()" required="true" size="14" placeholder="Postcode..." name="cookie" value="<?= $this->input->cookie('postcode', TRUE); ?>" >

<input type="submit" value="Zoeken">



</form>

<br /><br />

<form method="link" action="<?= base_url('bedrijven/all')?>">
<input type="submit" value="Alle bedrijven">
</form>

</div>
```

**Searchresults:**

```
<div style="clear: both; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
<div class="path"><?php echo $breadcrumbs ?></div>  
<div id="bigcontent">
<h1>Bedrijven gevonden: <?= count($query); ?></h1>
<?= br(1); ?>
<h2>Bedrijf:</h2>
<?= br(1); ?>
<hr/>
<?php foreach($query as $item):?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>bedrijven/<?= $item->idbedrijven?>"><h3><?= $item->Bedrijfsnaam   ?></h3></a>
    <p><b>Categorie:</b> <?= $item->Categorie ?></p>
    <p><small><?php echo $item->Profiel ?></p>
    <p><b><?php echo $item->Email ?></b></p>
    <p><b>Postcode:</b> <?php echo $item->Postcode ?></p>
    <p><b>Tags:</b></p>
    </small>
    <hr/>
<?php endforeach;?>
<br />
<<<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>">Terug</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use two different variables such as $match1 and $match2.

Comment: i tried that but it did not work. than it doesn't work at all.

Comment: the second query still overrides the first one. even when i do    $match = $this->input->post('search');
   $match2 = $this->input->cookie('postcode');
   $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2);

Comment: are you saying that if you use 2 different variables than none of the variables are receiving your desired values?

Comment: one 1 working. the other isn't so when i put $this->input->cookie above the input->post. only post works and cookie doesn't i want that they work both.

Comment: i think what you are saying is that $this->input->post is working every time, but $this->input->cookie isn't working anytime. there is something wrong with your code. check the user guide and the cookie helper. Or check this link http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Comment: no it's different. when the input->cookie is working the input->post isn't and vice versa. it's really strange.

Comment: it depends on which query i put last. when i switch them the one under the other query work. the query above isn't