# Search with two input fields in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search, cookies

I have a searchform to search factories in my database. my factories table has a field called 'postcode' now when you visit the site for the first time you have to type in your postcode. this will be saved in a cookie so you don't have to change it again.

Now i want to search for factories using a searchterm and the cookie 'postcode'

here is my searchform http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/

So something like this:

```
<form action="home/searchresults" method="post">
<input type="search" placeholder="search..." name="search">
<input type="search" value="<?= $this->input->cookie('postcode')?>">
</form>
```

and in my controller something like:

```
$match = $this->input->post('search');
$match2 = $this->input->cookie('postcode');

$data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2);
$this->load->view('views/header');
$this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
$this->load->view('views/footer');
```

in my model i have:

```
function get_search($match)
{
    $this->db->like('Bedrijfsnaam', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Postcode', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Plaats', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Telefoonnummer', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Email', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Website', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Profiel', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Adres', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Categorie', $match);

    $this->db->join('bedrijven', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven = bedrijven.idbedrijven');
    $this->db->join('categorieen', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen = categorieen.idcategorieen');
    $this->db->group_by('bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen');

    $query = $this->db->get('bedrijfcategorieen');

    return $query->result();
   }
```

But this does not work.
i asked a similar question here: [Prevent overriding queries in controller function - codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011313/prevent-overriding-queries-in-controller-function-codeigniter)

but no answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide 2 params for `$this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2);`, but then only provide one in the function itself : `get_search($match)`. So:

```
function get_search($match, $match2 = false)
{
    $this->db->like('Bedrijfsnaam', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Postcode', $match);
    //etc
    if($match2){
        $this->db->where('Postcode', $match2);
    }
}
```

...should work?

**UPDATED**

In chat it became obvious that it was better not to use active record, since it was a bit of a complex query. Instead, I offered this raw SQL:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM (`bedrijfcategorieen`)
JOIN `bedrijven` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven` = `bedrijven`.`idbedrijven`
JOIN `categorieen` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idcategorieen` = `categorieen`.`idcategorieen`
WHERE (`Bedrijfsnaam` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%'
OR `Plaats` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%'
OR `Telefoonnummer` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%'
OR `Email` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%'
OR `Website` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%'
OR `Profiel` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%'
OR `Adres` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%'
OR `Categorie` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%')
AND (`Postcode` = `".$this->input->post('cookie')."`)
GROUP BY `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven`";
```

... with this bit to retrieve the result set:

```
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

`$this->input->post('search')`and `$this->input->post('cookie')` can be replaced with `$match`and `$match2` in the above sql. I also suggested setting a default for the cookie, since it can be erased from the input field by the user; something like

```
$match2 = $this->input->post('cookie') ? $this->input->post('cookie') : 'default';
```

Comment: it does not work. only $match does work. $match2 doesn't it only searched for 1 parameter

Comment: What happens if you hardcode a postcode into your function, `get_search($match, 'your_postcode')`?

Comment: Also, the `if`condition might have to move to the bottom; updated my code above.

Comment: will try to put it at the bottom first.

Comment: you can see it yourself at http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/ just type in a postcode and save then click on the blue search button. it does not search on postcode but all of the factories in my table. and it did not work also when i put it on the bottom

Comment: Can you show what the query string looks like, using `$this->db->last_query();`?

Comment: where do i have to put that?

Comment: In your model instead of returning `query->result()`, return `$this->db->last_query();`- then echo it out in your view.

Comment: when you go to the page now and click search it searches factories based on the postcode. but now the other searchfield isn't working anymore http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28251/discussion-between-kees-sonnema-and-mudshark)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct, why don't you add another where statement after the like statements. something like this:

```
function get_search($match,$postcode)
{
    $this->db->like('Bedrijfsnaam', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Postcode', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Plaats', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Telefoonnummer', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Email', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Website', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Profiel', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Adres', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Categorie', $match);
```

$this->db->where("postcode",$postcode);

```
    $this->db->join('bedrijven', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven = bedrijven.idbedrijven');
    $this->db->join('categorieen', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen = categorieen.idcategorieen');
    $this->db->group_by('bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen');

    $query = $this->db->get('bedrijfcategorieen');

    return $query->result();
   }
```

update:

is your cookie set? and can you get the value properly? try this next scripts as controller. is should echo the cookie value to the screen. maybe it already goes wrong fetchhing the cookie value.

```
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    $match2 = $this->input->cookie('postcode');
echo "cookie value = ".$match2;

    $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2);
    $this->load->view('views/header');
    $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
    $this->load->view('views/footer');
```

Comment: will try this. it looks quite what i want.

Comment: it only works for one parameter. i don't know why. maybe it's a problem with my form.

Comment: look at http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/ when you set a cookie in the dialog you can see it in the searchbox on the main page. so fetching the cookie isn't a problem.

Comment: NOTE: i can search on cookie but then my other searchfield does not work. so it shows only the factories with the postcode. but i need to search for 1 factory. with searchterm and postcode.